# What should be the SDK path for android studio preview version?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install android studio preview version beta 3.4 
But I am confused that should I download the whole SDK again or give the same path as the stable version of Android studio has.

Comment: You can use the previous SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I download the whole SDK again or give the same path as the
>   stable version of Android studio has.

**YES** Use the same SDK. Just map the path. No need to download all SDKs again.